# Why do we mention Sukkos in the Haftorah bracha on Shabbos Chol HaMoed Sukkos but not Pesach in the Haftorah bracha of Shabbos Chol HaMoed Pesach?

Tags: passover, sukkot, chol-hamoed

In the final bracha after reading the haftorah on Shabbos Chol HaMoed Sukkos we say "...v'al haniviim v'al yom haShabbos haZeh *v'al Yom Chag HaSukkos HaZeh*", whereas on Shabbos Chol HaMoed Pesach we don't add in "v'al Yom Chag HaMatzos HaZeh". Why would that be?